# cannot find symbol of own class Java

Tags: java

I realise this has been asked a lot before but couldnt figure out the problem from those answers.

I have an abstract class Task:

```
package crowdtrust;

public abstract class Task
{

  public enum Type
  {
    BinaryImageClassification;
  };

  public abstract void assignCrowd();
};
```

an implementation task:

```
package crowdtrust;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class BinaryTask extends Task
{

  private List<SubTask> subtasks;

  public BinaryTask(String name, String question)
  {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.question = question;
  }

  public boolean assignSubtask(SubTask s)
  {
      return subtasks.add(s);
  }

  public void assignCrowd()
  {
    //TODO 
  }

};
```

and subtask class:

```
package crowdtrust;
public class SubTask {
  //not important
}
```

these are all in ct/src/crowdtrust

from ct i run this makefile:

```
CONTEXT   = webapps/ROOT
SRCDIR    = src

CLASSDIR  = $(CONTEXT)/WEB-INF/classes
LIBDIR    = $(CONTEXT)/WEB-INF/lib

JAVAC     = javac

SOURCES   = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/crowdtrust/*.java)
CLASSES   = $(SOURCES:.java=.class)

all: install clean

clean:
    rm -f $(CLASSES)

install: $(CLASSES)
    install -m600 $(CLASSES) $(CLASSDIR)/crowdtrust

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) -cp $(LIBDIR) $<
```

getting these (plus more similar) errors:

```
javac -cp webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib src/crowdtrust/BinaryTask.java
src/crowdtrust/BinaryTask.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Task
public class BinaryTask extends Task
                                ^
src/crowdtrust/BinaryTask.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SubTask
location: class crowdtrust.BinaryTask
  private List<SubTask> subtasks;
               ^
```

any ideas what's causing the error?

Comment: Not sure why you are using `make`. I prefer `maven`  The problem is that the classes you are trying to compile with are not in your class path, nor can they be found from the current working directory using the package.

Comment: Also, classes in Java does not end with a semi-colon. `Java != C++`

Comment: I added modified my makefile to use:

LIBDIR    = $(CONTEXT)/WEB-INF/lib:$(SRCDIR)/crowdtrust

but still the same error?

Comment: Try setting the LIBDIR to .;$(CONTEXT)/WEB-INF/lib for WINTEL. Use a colon if on Unix/Linux

Comment: ended up moving to maven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's not finding the dependencies properly and `BinaryTask` is getting compiled before `Task`. To resolve, please define explicit dependency in your make file as:

```
  SOURCES = Task.java SubTask.java BinaryTask.java
  BinaryTask.class: Task.class SubTask.class
```

Comment: this!
I tried manually compiling with:

`javac -cp webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib src/crowdtrust/BinaryTask.java src/crowdtrust/Task.java src/crowdtrust/SubTask.java` and it works

Comment: I'm unsure exactly how to write the makefile for many classes with many dependencies however. For example, if I have another class `C` which uses class `Task`, how do I (ideally in the general case) add this to my makefile?

Comment: Please refer this: http://ieng6.ucsd.edu/~cs131f/makenotes.html. It has  some details around dependency.

Comment: just to clarify if anyone searches this later. It was too complex to do with make easily and we moved ourproject over to maven